Hibernate @UniqueConstraint generates unexpected unique constraint on each column defined
With the Entity definition at the bottom, I am expecting only one unique constraint should be generated

unique(personNumber, isActive)

However, the ddl generated contains below unexpected additional constraints

unique(personNumber)
unique(isActive)

There is no @Column(unique = true) defined from both end of the mapping
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { 
@UniqueConstraint(name = "UniqueNumberAndStatus", 
columnNames = { "personNumber", "isActive" }) 
})


Hello what is your Hibernate version ? According to the documentation, it should work. documentation

It is the latest 6.x version
